# preg_replace hell

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to use preg_replace to get some data from a remote page, but I'm having a bit of an issue when it comes to sorting out the pattern.

```
function getData($Url){
    $str = file_get_contents($Url);
    if(strlen($str)>0){
        preg_match("/\<span class=\"SectionHeader\"\>title\</span>/<br/>/\<div class=\"header2\"\>(.*)\</div\></span\>/",$str,$title);
        return $title[1];
    }
}
```

Here's the HTML as is before I ended up throwing a million slashes at it (looks like I forgot a part or two):

```
<span class="cell CellFullWidth"><span class="SectionHeader">mytitle</span><br/><div class="Center">Event Name</div></span>
```

Where **Event Name** is the data I want to return in my function.

Thanks a lot guys, this is a pain in the ass.

Comment: I wouldn't touch this with a ten foot pole. There has got to be a more efficient way of getting the title than scanning the entire page for a match. You know preg_match will return an array if it located more than one match for that criteria, correct?

Comment: I'd use a html parser, such as http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Like so many times before on SO, I'd recommend not using regular expressions for parsing HTML since they aren't suited for that. Use a HTML parser instead.

Answer (score 0):

While I am inclined to agree with the commenters that this is not a pretty solution, here's my untested revision of your statement:

```
    preg_match('#\<span class="SectionHeader"\>title\</span\>/\<br/\>/\<div class="header2"\>(.*)\</div\>\</span\>#',$str,$title);
```

I changed the double-quoted string to single-quoted as you aren't using any of the variable-substitution features of double-quoted strings and this avoids having to backslash-escape double-quotes as well as avoiding any ambiguity about backslashes (which perhaps should have been doubled to produce the proper strings--see [the php manual on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)).  I changed the slash / delimiters to hash # because of the number of slashes appearing in the match pattern (some of which were not backslash-escaped in your version).

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things wrong with your expression:

- You're using `/` as the delimiter, but then use `/` unescaped in various places.
- You're escaping `<` and `>` seemingly at random. They shouldn't be escaped at all.
- You have some rogue `/`s around the `<br/>` for some reason.
- The class name for the div is specified as `header2` in the regex but `Center` in the sample HTML
- The title is `mytitle` in the HTML and `title` in the regex

With all of these corrected, you get:

```
preg_match('(<span class="SectionHeader">mytitle</span><br/><div class="Center">(.*)</div\></span\>)',$data,$t);
```

If you want to match any title instead of the specific title `mytitle`, just replace that with `.*?`.